# Reentrant Functions That Require Variable Averaging

Tags: c, reentrancy

This is a pretty basic one that I just can't think of a good solution for. I have some code that is a superloop type architecture (no OS). There are some veriables in functions that require averaging: i.e., need to have the same input result three times in a row to call a condition "True". My boss is now pushing to make all of these functions reentrant, which means my old method of static local variables is no good. He also doesn't want additional globals. So is there another good way to keep condition averaging for multiple contexts so as to allow the functions to be fully reentrant?

Example of current code:

```
 void foo (void)
    {
        static unsigned int ConditionCount = 0;

        if("SomeCondition" == TRUE)
            {ConditionCount++;}

        if(ConditionCount >= 3)
            {DoSomething();}
    }
```

Comment: What is the reason your boss suddenly wants these to be reentrant?

Comment: Actually, its a new boss who comes from a background w/ more RTOS development. My old boss was...me.

Answer (score 3):

To make it re-entrant, pass a pointer and let the caller maintain each `ConditionCount`.

```
 void foo (int *ConditionCount)
    {
        if("SomeCondition" == TRUE)
            {(*ConditionCount)++;}

        if(*ConditionCount >= 3)
            {DoSomething();}
    }
```

Comment: Ah, of course, I suspected that might be the answer. To add one more wrinkle: what if I said that there is an industry standard that specifically recommends "minimizing the use of pointers"?

Comment: pointers are not evil as such. They are perfectly valid scenarios when we need them. "Minimising" is alright, but you can't avoid it altogether if you are a C programmer.

Comment: This is usually seen as passing a pointer to a `struct` that contains all the context necessary, so some of us call it a context structure. It's also used to make code thread-safe, in which case you'll say you are passing "thread context" around.